# Object is not recognized while performing a mapreduce job

Tags: python, mapreduce, mrjob

Im trying to run a simple map reduce job and got the following datasets:

bike.txt

```
1   Bike 1
2   Bike 2
3   Bike 4
4   Bike 4
5   Bike 4
```

bikenames.txt

```
1,Aap
2,Noot
3,Greet
4,Mies
5,Gazelle
```

My aim is to write a mapreduce job that out the name of the bike that occurs most. Therefore I wrote the following:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep

class MostPopularBike(MRJob):
def configure_options(self):
        super(MostPopularBike, self).configure_options()
        self.add_file_option('--items', help='Path to u.item')

    def steps(self):
        return [
            MRStep(mapper=self.mapper_get_ratings,
                   reducer=self.reducer_count_ratings),
            MRStep(mapper = self.mapper_passthrough,
                   reducer = self.reducer_find_max)
        ]  

    def mapper_get_ratings(self, _, line):
        (bikeID, name) = line.split('\t')
        yield bikeID, 1

    def reducer_init(self):
        self.bikeNames = {}

        with open("bikenames.txt`") as f:
            for line in f:
                fields = line.split(',')
                self.bikeNames[fields[0]] = fields[1]

    def reducer_count_ratings(self, key, values):
        yield None, (sum(values), self.bikeNames[key])

    def mapper_passthrough(self, key, value):
        yield key, value

    def reducer_find_max(self, key, values):
        yield max(values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     MostPopularBike.run()
```

If I try to run it using:

```
!python MostPopularBike.py --items=bikenames.txt bike.txt
```

It trows the following error however:

```
AttributeError: 'MostPopularBike' object has no attribute 'bikeNames'
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`bikeNames` is only defined in `reducer_init()`, so this function must not be getting called. Anyway, it's not really an initialization function for each step; it looks more like initialization for the job.

Change the function name from `reducer_init` to `__init__` to perform the initialization when you create the `MostPopularBike` instance. Or if you really do want the initialization performed on each step, update your `steps` to this:

```
def steps(self):
    return [
        MRStep(reducer_init=self.reducer_init,
               mapper=self.mapper_get_ratings,
               reducer=self.reducer_count_ratings),
        MRStep(reducer_init=self.reducer_init,
               mapper = self.mapper_passthrough,
               reducer = self.reducer_find_max)
    ]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12712320)

Comment: @IanS, agreed. Edited my answer .